# How to have sub-workflows with the Slack Next Gen Platform

Tags: slack, slack-api, deno, slack-block-kit

The Slack Next Generation Platform is based on Deno (Javascript), which enables creating complex slack apps/bots hosted directly with Slack.

The current documentation only covers creating workflows from triggers, which are rather limited (basically either on a schedule, called manually, through a webhook or through events)

I want to set up a process, where a workflow can create multiple interactive messages, but from there each message would go through it's own workflow, meaning each message can have its own state independent of each other.

There is a possibility of setting up custom events, which would attach to messages as metadata and from there they could trigger workflows.

Would this be the way to go or is there a better solution?